# DataGridView Select Inserting New Columns Not Updating Existing Columns

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have created a DataGridView that uses a SQLAdapter to obtain its data.

I have pre-added the columns because I require 2 text columns and then several checkbox columns.

The values returned from the SQL Adapter are 0/1 indicating boolean values for the checkboxes.

However when the data is selected instead of updating the existing columns it is adding all the data in as additional columns again.

Why is it behaving in this why?

My code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    oCon = New SqlConnection
    oCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=*********;Initial Catalog=******;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*****;Password=*****"
    dsUsers = New DataSet
    daUsersList = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID , Username ,Active, Autosaint , Ladybird , Home , [Motor Trade] , First , Audit , Finance  FROM *******.dbo.******", oCon)
    '*** Define command builder to generate the necessary SQL
    Dim builder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(daUsersList)
    builder.QuotePrefix = "["
    builder.QuoteSuffix = "]"

    Try
        daUsersList.FillSchema(dsUsers, SchemaType.Source, "UserList")
        daUsersList.Fill(dsUsers, "UserList")
        tblUsers = dsUsers.Tables("UserList")
        DGVUsers.DataSource = tblUsers

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Something has gone wrong..." & vbNewLine & ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub
```

Screenshot

http://postimg.org/image/u6z1u5h5h/

Cheers.

Comment: @Plutonix I am literally doing that to pull the data into the DataGridView

Comment: @Plutonix http://postimg.org/image/u6z1u5h5h/ That is what is occuring, instead of it updating the checkboxes with ticks because of the '1'.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the Q - before you assign the datasource use `DGVUsers.AutoGenerateColumns = False`.  By default the DGV will add columns for you - it should know to use checkboxes for Bool though if you use the right datatype in the database (Bit)

Comment: @Plutonix Now it hasn't even added the data in to the DGV at all :-/

Comment: It never did - look at the image: the data shows in the auto-added columns not yours.  You ought not have to add the columns manually.  If the db datatype for the bools is `Bit` it will create checkbox columns for you.  To use your columns, you also have to set the `DataPropertyName` for each so it knows what to display in each

Comment: @Plutonix Sound that worked better :) Muchos Sir